# vscode mutiple selection + replace without mouse (windows 10)

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode, I want to select the word where current cursor in. and then press a key to select to next .... and then I replace the word I selected with new one

I tried "ctrl D", it  just select one by one, I don't know how to replace mutiplely

Comment: Use **Selection** | **Select All Occurrences**

Answer (score 0):

Use Vim extension inside of VSCode. Then, it becomes simply becomes a matter of:

```
/<wordtofind> <enter> caw <wordtoreplacewith> <escape>
n . n .
```

Explanation of above:

`/<wordtofind> <enter>` takes cursor to next occurence of `<wordtofind>`

`caw` - changes around word cursor is on and puts you in insert mode

`<wordtoreplacewith> <escape>` changes the word and then puts you back into normal mode.

`n . n .`

rinses and repeats the above action.

---

In ex editor, this becomes:

`:1,$s/oldword/newword/gc`

The `c` at the end asks you for confirmation before actually doing the change in each of the occurences.

Answer (score 0):

Just click a line using the mouse or move the cursor to your want line then press following buttons

alt + shift + Arrow Key(↑)